# Android -- Gmail API '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error while sending email

Tags: android, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to use Gmail API for sending emails using my Google account.

I have checked the main guide here : [Api Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android)

and used methods here : [Sending Email example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

Everything seems fine when authorizing the Api and using it in my activity. I can fetch information from my account successfully.

Unfortunately, I'm getting error while sending e-mail. I need help with this issue.

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
 public class SEND_EMAIL extends AsyncTask<MimeMessage, MimeMessage, MimeMessage>
 {

    @Override
    protected MimeMessage doInBackground(MimeMessage... mime_messages) {


        try {
            mService.users().messages().send(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, createMessageWithEmail(createEmail(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "Subject", "Hello Gmail.")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("AATS", "Trying to send email.");
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Methods that are being used from example:

```
public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject,
                                      String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(to));
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(bodyText);
    return email;
}

public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(baos);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
}
```

Libraries:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Base64;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;


import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;


import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
```

Function call:

```
private void refreshResults() {
        if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else {
            if (isDeviceOnline()) {
                new ApiAsyncTask(this).execute();
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
        }
        SEND_ASNYCTASK_EMAIL();
}

public void SEND_ASNYCTASK_EMAIL ()
{
   Log.i("AATS", "Sending email.");
   new SEND_EMAIL().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        refreshResults();
    } else {
        mStatusText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
    }
}
```

**---[EDIT 1]---**

After applying **gmail.compose** scope with [ND003](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4823789/nd003)'s suggestion, I got a new warning.

***Updated Trace:***

```
07-02 15:28:36.252  20997-21201/com.adak.aats.send_email W/﹕ Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
07-02 15:28:36.252  20997-21201/com.adak.aats.send_email W/art﹕ Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
```

**---[EDIT 2]---**
**[WORKING]**

I am still getting the same warning but the API works as intended and is able to send mails using my Google account.

Okey so, only thing I did was adding line:

```
compile files('libs/mail.jar', 'libs/activation.jar', 'libs/additional.jar')
```

in my build.gradle(Module: app) file in Android Studio. It's definitely not  understandable for me since I also have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

by default in my build.gradle file. So it should already compile all the .jar files in app/libs folder anyway. I wasn't getting any errors either while using javax library. Seems a bit strange for me, but still posted so maybe someone can clarify what's going on.

Thanks.

**-----------------------NOTE-------------------------**

Gmail API uses **javax.mail** and **javax.activation** libraries referred to **Sending Email example** on top *(can't share link due to low reputation).*

That's why you need to import these three files in your project, app/libs folder:  **mail.jar**, **activation.jar**, **additional.jar**.

**Referred answer:**  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: What is the scope you are using?

Comment: Actually i lack knowledge about it. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: In order to send emails, you need at least one of the following scopes of access:

{

https://mail.google.com/

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose

}

Refer https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Comment: I got you. In this case, i need to use compose scope i guess. Let me check. Appreciated.